# Reading a file inside reduceByKey() method in Spark - Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am working on a Spark application that expands edges by adding the adjacent vertices to that edges. I am using Map/reduce paradigm for the process where I want to partition the total number of edges and expand them in different worker nodes.

To accomplish that I need to read the partitioned adjacent list in the worker nodes based on the **key** value. But I am getting an error while trying to load files inside the **reduceByKey()** method. It says that the task is not serializable. My code:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {     
       SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("startingSpark").setMaster("local[*]");
       JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);               
       JavaRDD<String> file = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/mainFile.txt");
       ... ... ... //Mapping done successfully
       JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd1 = pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<String, String, String>() {
       @Override
       public String call(String v1, String v2) throws Exception {
          ... ... ...
          JavaRDD <String> adj = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/adjacencyList_"+key+"txt");
          //Here I to expand the edges after reading the adjacency list.
        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error **Task not serializable. Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable**. I think it is due to the fact that I am using the same spark context in the worker node as in the driver program. If I try to create a new Spark Context inside the **reduceByKey()** method, it also gives me an error saying that **Only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM**.

Can anyone tell me how can I **read a file inside the reduceByKey()** method? Is there any other way to accomplish my task? I want the expansion of the edges in the worker nodes so that they can be run in a distributed way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if this `JavaRDD <String> adj = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/adjacencyList.txt");` file small in size then read it outside the reducebykey as List<String> and broadcast the same. THe broadcasted variable can then be used inside reduceByKey

Comment: adjacencyList.txt is a big file. It is partitioned and kept inside the hdfs location. The partitions should be loaded inside the worker node base on the key value.